# Does this converge? $ \sum \frac{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}{n^2+1} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

As I checked on Wolfram Alpha I know that

$$
\sum \frac{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}{n^2+1} 
$$

Converges.

But have tried many tests to show that, without success. I tried ratio/root (inconclusive). Cauchy test ($ 2^k $ terms), compare with the limit. I also know that $ \ln ( n ) \lt \sqrt{n} $ when $ n \rightarrow + \infty $. Now any help is welcome.

Best regards.

Comment: Recall that $\log$ is dominated by any positive power of $n$ at $+\infty$.

Comment: $F(k)=\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty\frac{n^k}{n^2+1}\quad=>\quad F'\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)=\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty\frac{\sqrt n~\ln n}{n^2+1}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, $\ln n<n^{1/4}$, for $n$ sufficiently large, and hence
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}\ln n}{n^2+1}\le \frac{n^{3/4}}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}},
$$
for $n$ large enough, and as $\sum\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}$ converges, so does $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n}\ln n}{n^2+1}$.

Comment: Indeed, therefore we can upper bound with any $ n^k $ with $ \frac{1}{2} < k < 1 $?

Thank you.

Comment: It should be $0<k<\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Maybe we are talking about the same thing, since $ n^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot n^{k} $ with $ 0 < k < \frac{1}{2} \implies n^{k'} $ with $ \frac{1}{2} < k' < 1 $